# Error when converting VB.Net to C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I have this VB.Net function (*from other project*) which I need to convert into `C#`.

```
Private Function Convert(ByVal Value As String) As String
    Dim transformed = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value).Select( _
        Function(item) Not item)
    Return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(transformed.ToArray())
End Function
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
private string Convert(string Value)
{
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Enumerable.ToArray<byte>(Enumerable.Select<byte, byte>((IEnumerable<byte>)Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value), 
               (Func<byte, byte>)(item => ~item))));
}
```

I am getting two errors:

- Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
- Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.

I am not sure why LINQ Select converts the byte array to an int array, hence the explicit cast.

```
private string Convert(string value)
{
    var invertedBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value).Select(b => (byte)~b).ToArray();
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(invertedBytes);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this C# code.

```
private string Convert(string Value)
{
    dynamic transformed = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value).Select(item => (byte)~item);
    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(transformed.ToArray());
}
```

I have used this tool to convert - http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: OP is doing a bitwise-not operation in VB.NET, `~item` is the equivalent in C#. Your code wouldn't compile. Please verify.

Comment: @ChannappaJagadish , yes you are right, so i have updated my code, to make it compile, Thanks!